# Show count of multiple transformation output

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset, df, where the output of the sum and subtraction of a particular are revealed, however, I am wanting to show the count as well.

Data

```
    id  date1   pwr1    pwr2    positions
    aa  q122    2        2      100
    aa  q122    0        4      100
    bb  q122    5        0      50
    bb  q122    5        0      50
    bb  q222    0        0      50
    bb  q322    0        5      50
    bb  q322    0        5      50
```

Desired

```
   id   date    con retro   final   re_space con_count  retro_count
    aa  q122    2   6       -4      101       1          2
    bb  q122    10  0       10      48        2          0
    bb  q222    0   0       0       48        0          0
    bb  q322    0   10     -10      50        0          2
```

Doing

```
def f(x):
    d = {'con': [x['pwr1'].sum()],
         'retro': [x['pwr2'].sum()],
         'final': [x['pwr1'].sum() - x['pwr2'].sum()],
         're_space': [(x['pwr2'] !=0).values.sum() - (x['pwr1']!=0).values.sum()]}  # <<< HERE
    return pd.DataFrame(d)

out = df.groupby(['id', 'date1', 'positions']) \
        .apply(f).reset_index().drop(columns='level_3')




out['re_space'] = out['positions'].astype(float) + out.groupby('id')['re_space'].cumsum()
```

**Logic**

Counting any values under (consumed) pwr1 or (retro) pwr2, with the exception that the value is not 0.

This works, except, the con_count and retro_count are not shown in the output.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append this two lines to `d`:

```
d = {...
'con_count': [(x['pwr1'] > 0).sum()],
'retro_count': [(x['pwr2'] > 0).sum()],
...}
```

Full code:

```
def f(x):
    d = {'con': [x['pwr1'].sum()],
         'retro': [x['pwr2'].sum()],
         'final': [x['pwr1'].sum() - x['pwr2'].sum()],
         're_space': [(x['pwr2'] !=0).values.sum() - (x['pwr1']!=0).values.sum()],
         'con_count': [(x['pwr1'] > 0).sum()],
         'retro_count': [(x['pwr2'] > 0).sum()]}
    return pd.DataFrame(d)

out = df.groupby(['id', 'date1', 'positions']) \
        .apply(f).reset_index().drop(columns='level_3')

out['re_space'] = out['positions'].astype(float) + out.groupby('id')['re_space'].cumsum()
```

```
>>> out
   id date1  positions  con  retro  final  re_space  con_count  retro_count
0  aa  q122        100    2      6     -4     101.0          1            2
1  bb  q122         50   10      0     10      48.0          2            0
2  bb  q222         50    0      0      0      48.0          0            0
3  bb  q322         50    0     10    -10      50.0          0            2
```